# Postgresql server replication in local network

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have one postgresql server in my local network that hosts internal DB for internal ERP, eCommerce and some other tools. Nevertheless, I constantly add new rows to existing tables and since I do it over the network, the process not only slow, but it loads the server in the peak-hours.
I am thinking about inserting another server with postgresql on it and working with this intance, but I want some sort of replication- all new data that I add or modify on second instance, I want to be synced with 'main' server instance and vice-verse.
I have never done this before and any information would help.

Comment: How about Chapter 25 of PostgreSQL manual and chapter 14 of "PostgreSQL 9.0 High Performance" by Gregory Smith.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this via multi-master replication is a solution in search of a problem.  You are far better off optimizing your current approach than adding another complicated set of problems (multi-master replication) on top of your current ones.

If you really want to play around with multi-master replication in this way, bucardo is the tool to use.  However the rest of this answer will look to alternatives.

The first thing you really want to do is optimize your bulk loading.  The best way to do this is to ensure that your entire bulk load runs as a single transaction.  This reduces disk hits and it ensures that all the rows become visible at the same time.   If you are doing a lot of inserts and updates, you may want to load everything into a temp table first and then run a single query which updates your db from the temp table.  In Pg 9.2 you can set the temp table to be unlogged which will give you some performance benefits too (and since the data is transient WAL doesn't buy you anything).

The second thing you should do, after you verify your bulk loading is done in a sane manner is to carefully profile everything.  Bottlenecks are not always where you think they are and sometimes problems can be everything from triggers misbehaving to missing indexes.  But look at what the performance issues actually are at that point.  You may find that they are easy to fix.